# Если код написан в .NET с# и скомпилирован, можно ли его декомпилировать в другой язык .NET и получить рабочий код?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#

Весьма странный и глупый вопрос пришел в голову.

Если весь код конвертируется IL, то чисто в теории можно конвертировать код из IL в любой язык .NET семейства. (или внешний язык добавленный в .NET) через компиляцию + декомпиляцию.

Вопрос: на сколько код полученный таким способом будет чистым и читабельным?

Comment: в чем измерять чистоту и читабельность?

Comment: @Grundy отсутствие очень странных нечитабельных человеком конструкций в коде, если они отсутствуют в коде оригинального языка

Comment: а теперь, в чем измерять "нечитабельность"? :) Как определить, что вот эта конструкция странная и нечитабельная, а вот эта не странная и читабельная?

Comment: ILSpy умел в версии 2.<что-то там> декомпилировать в C# и VB, но нечитабельных конструкций оставлял много. Последняя версия хорошо декомпилирует в несколько версий языка C#, а VB оттуда убрали, или у меня просто обгрызенная версия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет нечитабельным. Весь вопрос тут только в реализации декомпилятора, что не является простой задачей. Декомпилятор из IL в F# вообще никто не делает (по крайней мере я не нашёл), и не думаю что он кому-то нужен.
А вот декомпилятор в C# например есть, по этому мы можем получить код на C# эквивалентный коду на F#... Вот только он ужасен. Так как эти языки действительно отличаются друг от друга **не только синтаксисом**, семантика F# просто ужасно выражается в C#.